# HTML Page Loading

Tags: javascript, html

I need the following:

I have an html page, which has declared several javascripts inside the body tag. However, I must make an asynchronous process prior to loading all of these components and render the page, and then continue the process. Any tips on how to solve this?

Thank you.

My code structure:

```
<html>
    <script>
        function loadFromServer() {
           //this operation is async, and I need to`enter code here` process this   before load  
           //the scripts declareds in body.
         }
     </script>
     <body>
         //content
         //js loads
     </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Developers can not ask here?

Comment: nex time I put my skills

Comment: Please show what have you coded so far and where you're stuck!

Comment: `nex time I put my skills` - how about you take the tour http://stackoverflow.com/tour

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried putting the scripts declaration after the body tag?

```
<body>
   ...
</body>

<!-- script declarations here -->
<script src=""></script>
<script src=""></script>
<script src=""></script>
```